# Change AppBar's icons depending on the Context (Fragments)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, appbar

I have my *AppBar* on my MainActivity. My MainActivity has a layout which works like a container of fragments.

What I want to accomplish is that I want my *AppBar* icons to change depending on which Fragment's on top at the moment.

something like this:

```
switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.semanario:
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewPagerMainContenedor, new FragmentSemanario());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
        myToolbar.SETICON(R.drawable.iconExample) (And how to change the xml atributte "app:showAsAction = always)
        break;
```

I thought about making an *AppBar* for each fragment but it should be easier than that, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method inside your main activity something like below :

```
updateToolbar(int title, int drawable){
 toolbar.setTitle(title);
 toolbar.setIcon(drawable);
}
```

and then call this method from your fragment :

```
getActivity().updateToolbar(title,R.drawable.icon);
```

To change action overflow icon :

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" 
parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
<item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow_menu</item>
</style>
```

For other custom icons you can simply update through thier views.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I dont have the method ".setIcon". Why? Maybe because im using support.v7.wiidget.Toolbar ?

Comment: try toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.my_icon); in case you are trying to change action over flow icon then you would have to use style.

Comment: setNavigationIcon changes the icon from the left. I need to set new icons at the right, the ones that i will use to make actions

Answer (score 0):

If your `AppBar` is different for some `Fragments` you should put the `AppBar` inside the `Fragment`. Right now you'll probably be able to manage changing your `AppBar` with the `FragmentTransactions` but later when you're building back/up navigation or deeplinking it will start breaking and you'll wish you would have put it inside the Fragment from the start.

EDIT: When the user clicks on a menu item you know what `Fragment` the user is navigating to because you're doing the `FragmentTransaction` yourself. However when the user presses the back button Android will do the `FragmentTransaction` for you and it becomes a lot harder to judge what `Fragment` the user is navigating to. You could loop through all `Fragments` in the `FragmentManager` and check what `Fragment` is visible but there might be multiple `Fragments` visible at the same time (e.g. `ViewPager` or tablet views). Managing `Fragments` and the back stack already is a pain in the *** when the user enters your app through a deep link.

When your app grows the navigation will become more and more complicated. Your future self will thank you for putting the `AppBar` in the `Fragment` instead of the `Activity` because you won't have to worry about keeping it in sync with the currently displayed `Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not understand well the justification of why it is not advisable to use the AppBar in the activity and the correct option to use is in each fragment separately. I will keep this in mind

Comment: I've edited the answer to elaborate more on the justification.